# How would you choose textures on a vertex to vertex basis with glb

Tags: c++, vulkan, gltf

How would you choose textures on a vertex to vertex basis with glb (gltf) files (using tinygltf)?

I am using the "tinygltf" library.

Suppose I have a square made up of 2 triangles and I have 2 textures. How would I map one texture to one triangle and the other texture to the other triangle?

That is the simplest form of my problem.

In reality I would have a complex mesh with multiple textures with each texture being used by a set of vertices.

I can't seem to find a vertex attribute that signifies which texture to use.

Comment: This is more a matter of how the data is being exported. Typically, if an object uses different materials on different triangles (and a texture is considered a material), then each set of triangles using the same material is a different "mesh". Some exporters may allow you to combine them so that you can use an array texture, but this would be a function of the exporter tool, not of gltf specifically. The GLTF file would still have to pass the data through, but step 1 is making sure that the data *exists* to be passed through.

Comment: It's common to define vertex attributes with, say, 100 vertices, and then within a Mesh, add four Primitives sharing the same vertex attributes. Each Primitive can have different _indices_ (drawing different triangles with a subset of the vertices) and different _Materials_ (specifying textures).

Comment: At the GPU level, textures are not stored at the vertex level, and you have a pretty modest number of texture units available on some devices (as low as 16) per material. Without getting into array textures, you'll probably want to think of each texture as a different material, and each material as a different draw call / mesh primitive.

Comment: In a gltf file you can have a single mesh with multiple textures and each vertex can have UV coordinates for mapping the textures so is there not something in the file that keeps track of which textures are mapped to which vertices.

Comment: Textures in glTF don't change per vertex. They are defined by the material, which in turn is assigned to a mesh.

Comment: In glTF, different textures are used for different purposes (baseColor, emissive, roughness, etc) and can all apply to all vertices of one material at the same time.  There is no case where two different baseColor textures exist in the same material, and certainly no case where vertex colors choose between materials.  However, a glTF "mesh" contains multiple glTF "primitives" (not the same as Vulkan), and each glTF primitive gets its own material, allowing multiple materials per glTF mesh.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I think I've got it now.